# Set a key with spaces in an associative array in Zsh

Tags: zsh, associative-array

In Bash (4 or above), if I have an associative array `dict`, I can set its value like `dict[apple count]=1` and I would be able to access it with `${dict[apple count]}`. Does Zsh allow space in key names? `dict[apple count]=1` doesn’t work in Zsh, so I guess Zsh has different syntax for this. `dict["apple count"]=1` doesn’t do what I want; instead of using `apple count` as the key, it is using `"apple count"` with quotation mark being part of the key.

Answer (score 5):

One (ugly) workaround is to use the syntax to “append elements to an ordinary array”, like

```bsh
dict+=('apple count' 1)
```

Zsh will maintain the property of associative arrays (as long as you declared it as one), so it will update the value if `dict['apple count']` exists. A less ugly way since Zsh 5.5 is:

```bsh
dict+=(['apple count']=1 ['orange count']=3)
```

Comment: also `typeset 'dict[apple count]'=1`

Comment: or `typeset dict['apple count']=1` zsh is even more quirkier than bash lol

Comment: @user414777 Do I understand it correctly that by `typeset dict['apple count']=1` the built-in `typeset` actually see `dict[apple count]=1` as `$1`?

Answer (score 5):

Zsh allows arbitrary strings as keys. The problem is with the parser.

To set an arbitrary key, using a variable works.

```
typeset -A dict
key='apple count'; dict[$key]=1
key=']'; dict[$key]=2
key=''; dict[$key]=3
printf %s\\n "${(k@)dict}"
```

[Unsetting a key is more difficult](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626393/in-zsh-how-do-i-unset-an-arbitrary-associative-array-element).